# std::set.insert won't compile with custom class

Tags: c++, class, insert, compilation, set

I have a class, Record, with three private integer fields, getters and setters, and a default and specific constructor. I intend to populate a set with Records, but am having issues getting the code to work.

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class Record
{
    int a, b, c;
    public:
    //getters and setters
    Record(){a = -1; b = -1; c = -1;};
}

int main()
{
    set< Record > s;
    s.insert(Record());
}
```

Attempting to compile results in this error:

> C:\Users\Denton\Documents\Indiana University\Class Documents\Spring
>   2013\CSCI-H2
>       12\Assignment9>g++ a9.cpp -o a9
>       In file included from c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/string:5
>       0:0,
>                        from c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/loc
>       ale_classes.h:42,
>                        from c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/ios
>       _base.h:43,
>                        from c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/ios:43,
>                        from c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/ostream:
>       40,
>                        from c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/iostream
>       :40,
>                        from a9.cpp:3:
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_function.h:
>   In member
>        function 'bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _
>       Tp = Record]':
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:1267:4:
>   inst
>       antiated from 'std::pair, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key,
>        _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key
>       = Record, _Val = Record, _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity, _Compare = std::l
>       ess, _Alloc = std::allocator]'
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_set.h:410:29:
>   insta
>       ntiated from 'std::pair,
>        _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set
>       <_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = Record, _Compar
>       e = std::less, _Alloc = std::allocator, typename std::_Rb_tree<_
>       Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>
>       ::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator, std::set<_Key, _Compare
>       , _Alloc>::value_type = Record]'
>       a9.cpp:72:28:   instantiated from here
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_function.h:236:22:
>   er
>       ror: no match for 'operator<' in '__x < __y'
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_function.h:236:22:
>   no
>       te: candidates are:
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:207:5:
>   note: t
>       emplate bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, co
>       nst std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:291:5:
>   not
>       e: template bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_It
>       erator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:341:5:
>   not
>       e: template bool std::operator<(const std::r
>       everse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2510:5:
>   no
>       te: template bool std::operator<(cons
>       t std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _
>       Traits, _Alloc>&)
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2522:5:
>   no
>       te: template bool std::operator<(cons
>       t std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2534:5:
>   no
>       te: template bool std::operator<(cons
>       t _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:1290:5:
>   note
>       : template bool std::operator<(const std::vector<_Tp, _
>       Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:1593:5:
>   note:
>       template bool std::operator<(const std::list<_Tp, _Allo
>       c>&, const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:856:5:
>   note: t
>       emplate
>        bool std::operator<(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _All
>       oc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_set.h:713:5:
>   note: te
>       mplate bool std::operator<(const std::
>       set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
>       c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_multiset.h:696:5:
>   not
>       e: template bool std::operator<(const
>       std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _All
>       oc>&)

insert works fine when I make a set s and s.insert(1)
What needs to be done for this code to compile?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to have `operator<` defined.

Comment: The Q&A I linked *seems* to be about `std::map` (from the title), but it is actually this very same issue (the mapped type is an instance of `std::set<>`).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to overload the `operator<` :
something like the following:

```
bool operator<(const Record& rhs) const 
{
   return a < rhs.a;  //assume that you compare the record based on a
}
```

The reason is that STL set maintains order on elements. std::set supports specifying a comparison function. The default is `less` which will use `operator <` to check equality.

Meanwhile, you have to end you class definition with `;` otherwise, compile error.

```
class Record
{
   int a, b, c;
   public:
   //getters and setters
   Record(){a = -1; b = -1; c = -1;};
}; //<---Cannot miss this ;
```

Comment: I have the semicolon ending my class definition on my actual code, sorry I left it out in this shortened version here. 

New compile error:

`x.cpp: In member function 'bool Record::operator<(const Record&) const':`

`x.cpp:30:38: error: passing 'const Record' as 'this' argument of 'int Record::g
etOrderNum()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @user2263849 where is your code for: Record::getOrderNum()?

Comment: @user2263849 you can see that code compiles OK here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/Ya3J3$0

Comment: `int getOrderNum(){return ordernum;};`

Comment: For the record regarding the follow-up comment: `int getOrdnerNum() const { return odernum; };` The function has to be const. Since it seems to be used by the operator< function, which is const too.