# std::set custom comparator for 2D points

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdset

I need a list of non-duplicated 2D points, so I use a `std::set` with a custom comparison function. The function I use has problems after inserting points because sometimes the `std::find` does not find the already inserted points.

```
const double tolerance = 0.1;
struct MyPoint2D
{
  MyPoint2D(double x, double y) : _x(x), _y(y) {}
  double _x, _y;
};
auto compMyPoint2D = [&](const MyPoint2D& pointA, const MyPoint2D& pointB) -> bool
{
  if (pointA._x < pointB._x - tolerance) return true;
  if (pointA._x > pointB._x + tolerance) return false;
  if (pointA._y < pointB._y - tolerance) return true;
  return false;
};
std::set<MyPoint2D, decltype(compMyPoint2D)> orderedMyPoints(compMyPoint2D);
MyPoint2D pointA(0.66,1.14);
MyPoint2D pointB(0.75, 0.0);
MyPoint2D pointC(0.57,1.19);
orderedMyPoints.insert(pointA);
orderedMyPoints.insert(pointB);
orderedMyPoints.insert(pointC);
if (orderedMyPoints.find(pointC)==orderedMyPoints.end())
{
  std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
  orderedMyPoints.insert(pointC);
  if (orderedMyPoints.find(pointC)==orderedMyPoints.end())
    std::cout << "Still not found" << std::endl;
}
```

Would I need to preorder the 2d points before inserting into the `std::set` or there is a better comparison function for 2d points?

I need to use `std::find` after inserting all points to obtain the final point indexes.

I'm using native C++ on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Good question and answers. My `std::map::insert` caused `heap-buffer-overflow` because of bad custom `operator<` implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your comparison function is wrong. Take out the +-tolerance. That's not useful when trying to determine an absolute order among floating point values. It doesn't enforce transitivity of equivalence, for example. That is, if `A == B` (i.e. `f(A, B)` and `f(B, A)` are both false) and `B == C`, then it is not necessarily the case that `A == C` when you have that tolerance adjustment in there.

Just do this:

```
if (pointA._x < pointB._x) return true;
if (pointA._x > pointB._x) return false;
if (pointA._y < pointB._y) return true;
return false;
```

Comment: thanks! My idea was to use `std::set` to clean the list of points and obtain as the same point two points closer than the tolerance (that's why the tolerance is so big, 0.1), but I see that it is not possible to do it with `std::set`.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, unless you have a reason not to, it's preferable to just define `operator<` for your class, this means less typing when using `std::set` etc, and means you can using infix `<`. Secondly, as Benjamin points out, there should be no need for `tolerance`. Thirdly, you can simplify the logic of the comparison.

You should have something like:

```
bool operator<(const MyPoint2D& lhs, const MyPoint2D& rhs)
{
    return lhs._x < rhs._x || (lhs._x == rhs._x && lhs._y < rhs._y);
}
```

Then you can just use `std::set<MyPoint2D>`.

Comment: If `A` is {0,1} and `B` is {1,0}, this will return true for both `A < B` and `B < A`, breaking antisymmetry.