# std::set use of operator<

Tags: c++, stl, set, operator-overloading

This question is kinda related to my other question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556428/set-of-custom-class-objects-and-their-operator) (see the discussion in comments). Basically, I had the following problem:

I have a class `node`. Which has some fields, the most important: `G`, `H` and `pos` (`pos` is a Qt's `QPoint`, but I've rewritten it for the sake of example to my own class `Point`. See the example below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>

class Point
{
public:
    int _x, _y;
    Point() : _x(0), _y(0) {}
    Point(int x, int y) : _x(x), _y(y) {}
    bool operator==(const Point& p) const { return _x == p._x && _y == p._y; }
    bool operator!=(const Point& p) const { return _x != p._x && _y != p._y; }
};

class node
{
public:
    node() {}
    node(const Point& p) : pos(p) {}
    bool operator==(const node& o) const { return pos == o.pos; }
    bool operator==(const Point& o) const { return pos == o; }
    bool operator!=(const node& o) const { return pos != o.pos; }
    bool operator<(const node& o) const { return G + H < o.G + o.H; }
    Point pos;
    std::shared_ptr<node> parent;
    int G = 0;
    int H = 0;
};

int main()
{
    node n1(Point(6, 7));
    n1.G = 1;
    n1.H = 1;
    node n2(Point(1, 1));
    n2.G = 2;
    n2.H = 2;
    node n3(Point(2, 2));
    n3.G = 1;
    n3.H = 1;
    std::set<node> nodes;
    nodes.insert(n1);
    nodes.insert(n2);
    nodes.insert(n3);
    auto min = (*std::min_element(nodes.begin(), nodes.end())).pos;
    std::cout << min._x << " " << min._y << '\n';
    std::cout << nodes.size() << '\n';
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
>main.exe
6 7
2
```

So the search for the lowest element was successful (using the `operator<`). So that's what I wanted. But as you can see, the three `node`s I created have different `.pos` fields (basically, coordinates). So I would like all of them to be present in a set. In other words, you can say that the "uniqueness" of every node should be determined by `.pos` field (actually using this field's `operator==`, which I defined above). And one of the nodes is considered not unique, cuz `std::set` used `operator<` for comparing its elements. So `n1` and `n3` have the same `G+H` value and they are considered equal (the `2` in the second line of the output is the number of set`s elements -> 2, not 3).

Before I knew about the `std::set`'s use of `operator<` to compare for equality, I've written `operator==` and `operator!=` thinking the set would use one of those to compare objects of my class. But it uses the `operator<`.

So my question here is why actually it uses this operator. Wouldn't it be easier to use `operator==` or `operator!=`?

For me, it kinda complicates the job, because I have to think of another way to write `operator<` or use a different container (therefore writing lambdas) or I can use `.pos` comparing in `operator<` and rewrite `std::min_element` myself (to take `G` and `H` sum in the account, not `.pos` field)

Comment: std::set is implemented as a binary tree - that requires you be able to compare entries for less-than relationships.

Comment: Oh, that would explain a lot. Don't actually know why my question got downvoted by someone, but still, thank you!

Comment: As an aside: your `operator!=` should use `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: strictly speaking it doesnt matter how `std::set` is implemented, the elements in a set are sorted and you cannot sort elements by using only `==` and `!=` you need `<`

Comment: So in this case I have to do either searching for the lowest element or the equality checking (checking if the element is already present in a container) manually :(

Comment: Suggestion: implement `!=` as `!(*this == p)`, in terms of equals negated.  Implement `>`, `>=`, and `<=` in terms of `<`.

Comment: Yeah, but still the set would use `operator<`, not `operator!=`, so even if I have `operator!=` written wrong, it doesn't matter here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting to achieve violates the [Strict Weak Ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) requirement of `std::set`. Basically, if you have 2 numbers, and neither is less then the other, they must be the same! They can't also be different (when checked using some different syntax).

All of your comparison operators should be defined consistently, so that there is a clear idea of *value* for your type. Which members of your type are *salient*, i.e. contribute to the value? There might be other members, but they should never be checked in the comparison operators.

An example is `std::vector`. If two `vector`s both contain `a, b, c`, they are equal. They might have a different amount of storage space left unused (`vector.capacity()`), but this is not part of the *value* of either object.

If you have the time, [John Lakos has presented about this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3xI1HJUy7Q), and [Alexander Stepanov has written about it](http://elementsofprogramming.com/).

Comment: The problem is, the sum of `G` and `H` should be used for the comparison of "which node is less` (the F value in A* algorithm), and the `.pos` field (node coordinates) should be used to distinguish one node from the other

Comment: I understand what you want to do. I'm trying to tell you it's a bad idea, and in particular inconsistent with the container you are trying to use. You have in mind two different concepts for the "value" of a node. I think you can achieve what you want by taking `.pos` into account in your `operator<`, but whatever you do, make sure `<` and `==` (and all the rest) agree with each other!

Comment: Thank you, that's what I will do. I just was confused why would `std::set` use `operator<` for equality or uniqueness checks, but now when I know it's based on a binary tree - it all seems clear! But still I don't know which rule of SO I broke that I get downvotes :( I thought I stated my question clear, provided a complete example, wrote maybe not 100% perfect but I guess understandable english, I don't know. I guess I should read the rules again